# How to disable HTTPS on tomcat and have it run on port 8080?

Tags: http, tomcat, server.xml

I have the following connectors in my server.xml. My app runs on port 8080 and I no longer would like it to run on port 8443. How can I modify the connector to disabl HTTPS and only have tomcat run on 8080? Thank you

```xml
    <!--
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->
    <!-- Define a SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the NIO implementation that requires the JSSE
         style configuration. When using the APR/native implementation, the
         OpenSSL style configuration is required as described in the APR/native
         documentation -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
    -->
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               SSLEnabled="true" maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               keystoreFile="tomcat.keystore" keystorePass="changeit" sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"
               ciphers="TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256"/>
```

Comment: Already tried to enable the first and disable the last `Connector`?

Answer (score 2):

You need a single `Connector`:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000" />
```

and comment out your port 8443 Connector.

This will listen on the shutdown port (defined in your `Server` stanza, defaults to 8005) and port 8080 only.  Note, however, that if the client code wants to upgrade to HTTPS it will fail as you no longer have the `redirectPort`.

Comment: How do you know OP's actual shutdown port is on 8005?

Comment: The default value for `redirectPort` is actually 443, (since at least [Tomcat 7](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/e498667bd7811e846771a852b16ce9f1e524b81b/java/org/apache/catalina/connector/Connector.java#L143)). To disable the redirect port you need to explicitly set it to 0 or less (cf. [source code](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/e498667bd7811e846771a852b16ce9f1e524b81b/java/org/apache/catalina/realm/RealmBase.java#L902)). Let's say **-1**.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz - but the `server.xml` that is distributed has 8443 so that it can run without root in Unix environments.  This is from Tomcat 9.  I have verified that removing the redirectPort doesn't create any other ports and an `lsof` shows just two ports in LISTEN.

Comment: I agree on the number of listening ports, but I don't agree on _"if the client code wants to upgrade to HTTPS it will fail..."_. If a `<security-constraint>` is specified Tomcat will redirect the client to port 443. If you set `redirectPort="-1"` Tomcat will immediately issue a `403` HTTP error.

Answer (score 1):

As seen from your original code, please uncomment the port="8080" section and comment out the port="8443" section as follows,

Please note that the meaning for redirectPort="8443" is explained in details [here](https://serverfault.com/a/758856)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22g5H.png)

Answer (score 1):

```
This will work

  
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    
    <!-- Define a SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the NIO implementation that requires the JSSE
         style configuration. When using the APR/native implementation, the
         OpenSSL style configuration is required as described in the APR/native
         documentation -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
    -->
<!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               SSLEnabled="true" maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               keystoreFile="tomcat.keystore" keystorePass="changeit" sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"
               ciphers="TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256"/>
-->
```